# How to define the directory of a named volume in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose similar to this one

```
services:

  service-a:
    image: "service-a"
    volumes:
      - /home/user/data:/data

  service-b:
    image: "service-b"
    volumes:
      - /home/user/data:/data

  service-c:
    image: "service-c"
    volumes:
      - /home/user/data:/data
```

I'd like to use a named volume for all 3 to simplify it and make it more manageable, like this

```
services:

  service-a:
    image: "service-a"
    volumes:
      - namedvolume:/data

  service-b:
    image: "service-b"
    volumes:
      - namedvolume:/data

  service-c:
    image: "service-c"
    volumes:
      - namedvolume:/data

volumes:
  - namedvolume
```

The thing is that i need to insert some files into `namedvolume`, so I'd like to have it binded to a local directoy like it was before. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Docker: change folder where to store docker volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396139/docker-change-folder-where-to-store-docker-volumes) lists out a couple of options, and in particular details how to create a named volume that's actually a bind mount; does one of those approaches work for you?

Comment: @DavidMaze I think one of them might suit me, Im going to check and I'll update